# formatting date from long format to short in portuguese

Tags: php, date, format

I have a date written in portuguese like this "24 de novembro de 2018"
This date is equivalente to "24 november 2018"
I want to get both day and month number so it echos me

24 and 11 I have already tried this and it gives me 31/12/1969 ????

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'portuguese');
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');    
echo date("d/m/Y",strtotime($date));
```

Comment: "strtotime — Parse about any **English** textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp"

Answer (score 0):

```
echo date("d/m/Y", strtotime("24 november 2018"));
```

Otherwise it returns false on your date and takes to you back to the beginning of (machine) time :)

Answer (score 0):

As dates are parsed in english I had to cut string and switch case. The result is as following:

```
        $strArray = explode(' ', '24 de novembro de 2018');
        $post_day = $strArray[0];
        $post_month = $strArray[2];

        switch ($post_month){

    case "janeiro": $post_month = "January" ; break;
    case "fevereiro": $post_month = "February"; break;
    case "março": $post_month = "March" ; break;
    case "abril": $post_month = "April"; break;
    case "maio": $post_month = "May"; break;
    case "junho": $post_month = "June"; break;
    case "julho": $post_month = "July"; break;
    case "agosto": $post_month = "August"; break;
    case "setembro": $post_month = "September"; break;
    case "outubro": $post_month = "October"; break;
    case "novembro": $post_month = "November"; break;
    case "dezembro": $post_month = "December"; break;

        }           

        $post_month = date_parse($post_month);
        $post_month = $post_month['month'];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:i hope it will help you.

```
$date="24 de novembro de 2018";
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'portuguese');
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');    
echo date("Y-F-d",strtotime($date));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use strftime() instead date()**

To get a date formatted in different languages you have to use strftime() and setlocale() functions in PHP instead of date(), which always returns date in English.

From PHP.net documentation

> To format dates in other languages, you should use the setlocale() and
> strftime() functions instead of date().
>
> https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

**Example**

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR');
echo strftime("%d de %B de %Y"); //  08 de fevereiro de 2021
```

**Linux can't find your locale**

If you're Linux server don't show the strftime() with the defined setlocale(), maybe you need to install locale packages:

**check current installed languages:**

```
locale -a
```

**install pt language package**

```
apt-get install language-pack-pt 
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

(Select locales you need)

**restart apache**

```
apache2ctl restart
```

> Reference:
> https://www.vextenso.com.br/blog/87/php-setlocale-linux-pt_BR-locale-nao-funciona.html